# Cobbler 2.2.2 problems

Tags: linux, cobbler

I have setup a dedicated LAN for Cobbler tests. My setup is:

```
Cobbler server: openSUSE 12.3, cobbler 2.2.2 (from openSUSE repos)
Imported distros: Centos 6.5, Red Hat 6.5, Red Hat 7.0, openSUSE 13.1
Target Machine: VMs in a Windows 7 Virtualbox
```

Systems provisioning works OK, but I have some problems. 
The first one is that cobbler does not honor the "**pxe_just_once: 1**" setting.

When the setup of the target OS is finished, after the reboot the target systems continues to PXE boot! 
The second problem is that the target server is not correctly configured!
See my setup:

```
cobbler system report --name=test
Name                           : test
TFTP Boot Files                : {}
Comment                        :
Fetchable Files                : {}
Gateway                        : 192.168.0.1
Hostname                       : testcob1.example.com
Image                          :
IPv6 Autoconfiguration         : False
IPv6 Default Device            :
Kernel Options                 : {}
Kernel Options (Post Install)  : {}
Kickstart                      : <<inherit>>
Kickstart Metadata             : {}
LDAP Enabled                   : False
LDAP Management Type           : authconfig
Management Classes             : []
Management Parameters          : <<inherit>>
Monit Enabled                  : False
Name Servers                   : ['192.168.0.1', '8.8.8.8']
Name Servers Search Path       : []
Netboot Enabled                : False
Owners                         : ['admin']
Power Management Address       :
Power ID                       :
Power Password                 :
Power Management Type          : ipmitool
Power Username                 :
Profile                        : RHEL-6.5-x86_64
Proxy                          : <<inherit>>
Red Hat Management Key         : <<inherit>>
Red Hat Management Server      : <<inherit>>
Repos Enabled                  : False
Server Override                : <<inherit>>
Status                         : testing
Template Files                 : {}
Virt Auto Boot                 : <<inherit>>
Virt CPUs                      : <<inherit>>
Virt Disk Driver Type          : <<inherit>>
Virt File Size(GB)             : <<inherit>>
Virt Path                      : <<inherit>>
Virt RAM (MB)                  : <<inherit>>
Virt Type                      : <<inherit>>
Interface =====                : eth0
Bonding Opts                   :
Bridge Opts                    :
DHCP Tag                       :
DNS Name                       :
Master Interface               :
Interface Type                 :
IP Address                     : 192.168.0.200
IPv6 Address                   :
IPv6 Default Gateway           :
IPv6 MTU                       :
IPv6 Secondaries               : []
IPv6 Static Routes             : []
MAC Address                    :
Management Interface           : True
MTU                            :
Subnet Mask                    : 255.255.255.0
Static                         : True
Static Routes                  : []
Virt Bridge                    :
```

So, although I have setup the hostname and the network interface of the target system, after the setup, the hostname is set to localhost.localdomain and eth0 is configured as a DHCP not static!

How can I find the problem and fix it?

Note that I have synced and restarted cobbler a couple of times, but the problems persists.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer for at least one part of my question.
In order to setup a specific hostname, ip, etc you need to configure the MAC of the target system.

Still, I have not found an answer for the *pxe_just_once: 1* problem.